# Why deconvolution is in an ill-posed problem?

Tags: fourier-transform, convolution

The deconvolution problem is to find a function $u(\mathbf x)$ from the equation:
$$
K * u(\mathbf x) = \int_{M} K (\mathbf x - \xi) u(\xi) d \xi = f(\mathbf x)
$$
It is said in my lectures that in the case of finite $f$ and $K$ the problem is ill-posed. From the convolution theorem follows, that:
$$
u(\mathbf x) = \int_{M} e^{i \omega \mathbf x} \frac{\tilde{f}(\omega)}{\tilde{K}(\omega)}
$$
Then it is stated, that in the latter integration the integration is over the whole space, and the frequencies $\omega$ can be very high due to the noise, and the integral may fail to converge.

In the first equation the action on the $u$ is well defined, however, do I correctly understand, that there can be none or more than one functional satisfying this equation, and this is reflected in the fact, that the lattter integral may be not defined?

Comment: the phrase "Ill-posed" means a lot of different things to different people. Perhaps in this situation they mean in the sense that -- on paper -- these equations work out fine. however, if $f$ is perturbed by even a small amount of noise, it could be that the recovery may be wildly different from the original

Comment: @Zim, there are lectures on Scientific Computing, so it seems like the meaning is that it hard to perform it by numerical methods, but maybe there is also some purely mathematical insight